# Pausing setInterval during event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a stopwatch feature that is toggled by a start/stop button.  When the stop button is pushed, the timer stops, and jQuery inserts a row into a table that is preloaded onto the page.

I have another jQuery script running in the background that continously updates that table to maintain fresh data. It's essentially a timekeeper.

However, the issue I have is that when a user pushes the stop button, the setInterval load keeps running, causing the added jquery field to disappear.

I have tried adding a variable to check if the stop button was pushed, and if so, stop the event...but since it's already loaded in the DOM, it didn't seem to work.  Here's the current code:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getData.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#timesheet").html(data);
                }
            });

            var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getData.php?randval='+ Math.random(),
                    success: function(data) {
                        $("#timesheet").html(data);
                    }
                });
            }, 9000);
```

Here's the HTML data that the ajax is loading:

```
<table>
<tr><th>Test</th></tr>
<tr><td>Test</td></tr>
</table>
```

I have also tried using append on tr:last, but that just appended it to the tr...rather than creating a new tr.

TL;DR: I want setInterval to not override the field that jQuery adds when a button is pushed, but can't seem to do that since it's coded to change the entire table.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ClearInterval explained](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

```
$('#button').click(function()
 {
     clearInterval(refreshId);
 });
```

Comment: Hiya, howz it going `:)` +1 to you as well - but just for sharing only as you mentioned w3schools link => http://w3fools.com/ - I had a laugh on that; when someone shared this with me - w3school ( not an official w3c site) aint got anything to do with w3c `:P`

Comment: I read from multiple sources to cross-check what I learn. w3school used to be the last place [not user-friendly to me]. I wouldn't post a link to wrong information. Thanks for enlightening me with that link

Comment: No worries at all `:)` Glad for sharing that, neah link is fine just a thought: to share the w3school story

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in `.Pause` API, but you can stop it, and then start a new interval with the same function.

Something like `clearInterval` and then set it back again.

Answer (score 1):

```
var MyApp ={
 animationID: null,
 speed : 200,
 setAnimation:function(state){
         var obj=this;
         if(state)obj.animationID=setInterval(function() { 
             //your code
             },obj.speed);
         else {
             clearInterval(obj.animationID);
             }
         }
}
```

to start

```
MyApp.setAnimation(true);
```

to stop

```
MyApp.setAnimation(false);
```